# Memory not being released by httpx

Tags: python, memory-leaks, aiohttp, httpx

So I've been struggling to find a solution here that doesn't require me ripping out httpx and replacing it with another library, especially since the availability of http2/async libraries is slim to none.

While I wait for the team at httpx to get back to me, I wanted to do a sanity check here to see if what I'm seeing is really a potential problem with the library or if it is my inexperience.

Code:

```
import httpx
import asyncio
from memory_profiler import profile
import aiohttp


@profile(precision=4)
async def memory_test(url):
    
    '''
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            html = await response.text()    
            print(f'Length of response is: {len(html)}')
    '''
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True) as client:
        
        html = await client.get(url, follow_redirects=True)
        print(f'Length of response is: {len(html.text)}')   
        
    del html    
    return None

async def main():
    url = 'https://www.autoscout24.fr/offres/bmw-320-serie-3-touring-e91-touring-163ch-pack-m-sport-diesel-bleu-671904de-6139-4061-a451-f63bdb61de2b'
    result = await memory_test(url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Running that through memory profiler gives me:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    10  84.7266 MiB  84.7266 MiB           1   @profile(precision=4)
    11                                         async def memory_test(url):  
    12                                              
    13                                          '''
    14                                          async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    15                                              async with session.get(url) as response:
    16                                                  html = await response.text()    
    17                                                  print(f'Length of response is: {len(html)}')
    18                                          
    19                                          '''
    20  89.1055 MiB   1.8125 MiB           4    async with httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True) as client:
    21                                              
    22  88.2461 MiB   1.7070 MiB          91        html = await client.get(url, follow_redirects=True)
    23  89.1055 MiB   0.8594 MiB           1        print(f'Length of response is: {len(html.text)}')   
    24                                          
    25                                          
    26  89.1055 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1    del html    
    27  89.1055 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1    return None
```

Where a 300kb page ends up taking up 4mb+ of memory that isn't ever released. Running a few thousand URLs through this quickly eats up all the memory I've got available.

When switching to aiohttp however, this looks different:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    10  84.6523 MiB  84.6523 MiB           1   @profile(precision=4)
    11                                         async def memory_test(url):  
    12                                              
    13                                          
    14  88.2812 MiB   0.0000 MiB           3    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    15  88.2812 MiB   2.2344 MiB           7        async with session.get(url) as response:
    16  88.2812 MiB   1.3945 MiB           3            html = await response.text()    
    17  88.2812 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1            print(f'Length of response is: {len(html)}')
    18                                          
    19  88.2812 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1    '''
    20                                          async with httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True) as client:
    21                                              
    22                                              html = await client.get(url, follow_redirects=True)
    23                                              print(f'Length of response is: {len(html.text)}')   
    24                                          '''
    25                                          
    26  87.6484 MiB  -0.6328 MiB           1    del html    
    27  87.6484 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1    return None
```

Is this an issue with httpx, or am I expecting something that isn't realistic from Python?
Ref: https://github.com/encode/httpx/discussions/2414

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend as a next step that you post a Minimal Reproducible Example that uses multiple URLs and that actually causes the process to run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Having taken Tim Boddy's advice, I extended my test to request a URL multiple times and see if an actual OOM issue can happen. After running the function above 150 times, getting a 100kb page, I see that the memory usage levels out quite quickly and that at the end of the run there is only a ~5mb increase in usage.

The code for this test can be seen at https://github.com/encode/httpx/discussions/2414